# Elasticsearch service stops after a few hours

Tags: linux, service, elasticsearch, vps

I've installed elasticsearch on a vps server which runs linux. The version is 1.4.4. I get the following warning message during start :

Starting elasticsearch:                                    [  OK  ]
root@vps15042 [~]# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (common)
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for morefo.

The service starts well but stops by itself after a while. I must log as root and restart it each time. Note that the website is not yet on production and there is just some test data.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It could be OOM issues , can you go through other logs and inspect using debug logs too

Comment: there is not much log files in the log folder. The logs for each day contains less than 100 lines. I've tried to set mlockall" : true, but it is still crashing during use after a while.
 I've also set action and gateway to INFO. 
What else can cause the service to run out of memory? I am also getting the following error :
 error: permission denied on key 'vm.max_map_count'. 
Can this be the cause?
Else, what can be done to prevent the log4 warning?

Comment: You can check with `dmesg` and see if the OOM killer is triggered.

Comment: I cannot see anything through dmesg. I've used pmap to track the process id over a short period of time and I can conclude that it keeps increasing. So it may well be an OOM issue. What can thus be done to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @YashinSoraballee You can check [Limiting Memory Usage](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html) and also make sure that other processes on the system are not consuming RAM. However, you should see some info in `dmesg` when the OOM killer is triggered. Also, you can monitor the RAM (and swap as well).

Comment: My dmesg is an empty file.

I have changed two things on the etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch file in an attempt to increase memory for es :

ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited


i've also set "mlockall" : true

There is 4gb of ram in my VPS. After making those changes, the % mem for the elastic process has increased from around 7% to 64%. below are rhe figures am getting from "top". However es is still crashing :(. Could it be related to log4j warning?



  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

26096 elastics  20   0 20.0g 2.6g 113m S  1.0 64.5   0:09.98 java

Comment: Please ca anyone can help me on this??

Answer (score 1):

I changed the host and it's working fine now!
I guess, it was something to do with the VM of the VPS, which elasticsearch couldn't change.